# convert json to python class using elasticsearch_dsl

Tags: python, elasticsearch-dsl

I feel like this should be a simple question -- I want to take a json response and map it to a class using [elasticsearch_dsl](https://elasticsearch-dsl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/persistence.html) + python:

```
response = requests.get(get_url() + id)
data = response.json()

Item.init()
item = Item(data)
item.save()
```

I can't seem to find a way to mass assign all fields without having to do something like

```
item.condition_id = data['condition_id']
```

There has to be a way to convert the json object to the class... right?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `Item(**data)` to construct an object from a dict.